# Client-side technology for big web application

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, client-side

I get order to develop web application (as SAAS). Something like ZohoCRM.
It's my first so complicated app.

**Key requirements are:**

- One page app (no page refresh)
- Easy features adding
- Modularity
- **UPD:** Real time data exchange: users-server-users (sockets or
  long-polling)

So I'm struggle to cope with Javascript (jQuery) and Flash (Flex).

**Thoughts about Javascript:**

Pros: pluginless, supporting by tablets and smartphones browsers, lightweight (loading faster).
Cons: a lot of job on cross-browsing issues, viewable sources.

**Thoughts about Flash:**

Pros: no need to fudge with cross-browsing, rich components customization.
Cons: require plugin, not clear situation with Apple products.

So which way I have to go?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD#1:** It will be a web based application for business. First part is basic CRM functionality. Later step-by-step it'll get ERP features.
Main data operations will be with tables and trees with filtering.
Must work just in browsers so far. But I'm sure that later will appear requirements for tablets and smartphones support.

**P.S.** After thinking and googling I more and more inclining to Javascript stack (jQuery, backbone and underscore).

Comment: Your description is to broad and it will most likely start a flame war. If you really want help deciding which path to take you should give more information about the planned application(target, content...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pro's you mention for JavaScript is the reason you should use JavaScript. Mobile is getting more and more important on the web.

Flash is slow, (compared to JavaScript) and there's enough functionality on JavaScript.

Using jQuery for example takes care of cross-browser issues.

Comment: I agree that HTML/JS is generally a better choice for web apps as long as there is no requirement for features that is not available (like camera access). But regarding "Flash is slow, (compared to JavaScript)", can you back that up with some hard facts? In my experience, the mantra that Flash is slow and a CPU hog mainly stems from a time when rich UI and animation was almost always done in Flash, but when similar things now is done in HTML/JS, it is generally as slow and CPU intensive. More on the subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576565/why-is-flash-so-hard-on-the-cpu/

Comment: Good Comment Lars. It is more that I assumed that because I heard others about this. No real hard facts.